# Select object value

Tags: javascript

I just saw the following:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp

And wonder if there's something wrong with *selectObject.value*. Why not a simple approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function displayResult(){
                    alert(document.getElementById("mySelect").value);
                }
            </script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            Select your favorite fruit:
            <select id="mySelect">
                  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
                  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
                  <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
                  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">
            Display value of selected fruit
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems to be working with no problem.

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Comment: [Don't pay too much attention to w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: Radio buttons require a convoluted process to access, but I've never had similar issues with `<select>` inputs.

Comment: Well, I've thought for years that you had to go the way of using the `selectedIndex` when getting a `select`s value. However, reviewing [MDN's information on `select` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement#Properties), it appears I was wrong and it *is available* for accessing the (first) `option` element's selected value. Am I missing something, or was I just lead astray? Now I'm wondering if the `selectedIndex` was was meant for accessing multi-`select` `value`s. Anybody care to disabuse me, please be my guest. Also, MDN is a legitimate resource for learning.

Comment: @Pointy: It's not just W3Schools -- I've seen that method in many other references too.

Comment: You might take a look at [MDN's Javascript Learning offerings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript), as well as the articles offered on the [MDN Javascript Reference site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript). But yeah, w3schools is a bit discredited on SO, even though probably most of it is not "wrong". Just not necessarily dependable credible (http://w3fools.com).

Answer (score 5):

Your method, `document.getElementById("mySelect").value` is returning the value of the select object - which sets itsself to the value of the currently selected option. The way w3Schools is doing it is finding the actual option tag, then you're getting the value of the option tag. So, as long as you are accessing the currently selected option tag, they return the exact same thing. However, the w3schools way allows you to actually set the value of the option tag instead of changing which option is selected when setting the value property (although that's probably not what you want).

**Example:**

```
​<select id='select'>
    <option value=1>one</option>
    <option value=2>two</option>
​</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

```js
x=document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
```

So, `document.getElementById('select').value;` returns the value of the *select element*.

And `document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value​;` returns the value of the *selected option element*.

Meaning that `document.getElementById('select').value​=2​​​​` changes *which option is selected*, while `document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value​=2` changes *the value of the selected option element*.

**TLDR: When getting the value there is no difference, when setting the value there is.**